# Check if HTML5 Video is Completely Played

Tags: jquery, html, events

I want to check if something is done and than I want to be redirrected to the next page.

The code I have now is:

```
<video id='full_screen' autoplay>
    <source src='videos/vid1.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>


<script src='http://localhost/shared/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script>
<script>
    $('video').done(function() {
        window.location.replace('index.php?part=2&name=".$name."');
    });
</script>
```

Should I use a delay to redirrect or can it be done this way?
Pleas

Comment: do you mean the video was done completely played?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to redirect the page after the completion of the video, so this:

```
$("video").bind("ended", function() {
   //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select your video and apply a simple jquery event listener/callback like so:

```
// Select video player.
var $video = $("#video");
// Bind events.
$video.on("ended", function(){
    window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
});
```

You can see the other events you can bind to here (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_av_dom.asp) in the event you need to add more functionality.

Cheers.

Comment: He was asking for the code to check when the video had played completely, not the redirection code.

Comment: please don't use w3school resources... :(

Comment: There's no need to have prejudices against content for the sake of it. The page I cited has a correct list of DOM events for the HTML5 video/audio element, and more importantly it's easy to read.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `onended` event:

```
<video id='full_screen' autoplay onended="videoEnded()">
    <source src='videos/vid1.mp4' type='video/mp4'>
</video>
```

then js:

```
function videoEnded() {
    window.location.replace('index.php?part=2&name=".$name."');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pure javascript I think can work on this?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var video = document.getElementById('full_screen');

        video.onended = function(e) {
        //redirect here
        window.location = "http://somewhere.com";
     }
</script>
```

**reference**: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#event-media-ended